# Connecting to localDB in Rider gives the wrong DB

Tags: localdb, datagrip, rider

https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2016/10/07/connecting-datagrip-to-sql-server-express-localdb/

The description above worked fine. But the opened DB contains system tables like spt_monitor, spt_fallback_dev. (sqllocaldb.exe i showed only one localdb)

I have an mdf file which contains the DB I want to use. Any idea? (I tried to give the full name of the mdf file in the uppermost Database field, but it did not help)

[image]

One more info: In visual studio sql server object explorer, I see the system databases and the mdf files as well. In vs / server explorer I can connect to the mdf file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

after giving username and password go to schema tab
    (exit from visual studio)
    check the mdf file, check the relevent schema, e.g. dbo
    if you missed this step then database double click on "connection / schemas" to make the check